# Chrome blocking Iframe from external system "Set-Cookies" header with warning: "This Set-Cookie was blocked due to user preferences"

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, iframe

I build a web application that embeds a Qlik Sense iframe, which means an iframe from an external server. This is how the fetch call looks like:

```
  return fetch("https://servername/prefix/qrs/about?xrfkey=<key>", {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Qlik-xrfkey': '<key>',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
  }).then(response => {
    return response.status === 200;
  });
```

For authentication to the Qlik iframe I'm using the JWT, which I register in Qlik Sense. As a reply I get a response header "Set-Cookie" and the according session token. **However Chrome seems to block the cookie with the warning "This Set-Cookie was blocke due to user preferences".** It works in Edge and Firefox.

Since I'm developing, I'm using "localhost:8080". I read that Chrome ignores cookies on http://localhost, so I've tried using SSL -> "https://localhost:8080" which didnt work. Additionally, I've tried via IP, so "https://127.0.0.1:8080", didnt work either.

Moreover, I configured the backend (Qlik Management Console) such that SameSite = None and that it uses the "Secure" attribute, since I read that this might cause issues as well. Plus I'm using the
`credentials 'include'` attribute.

These are my request headers
[Request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTgT5.png)

and here are the response headers
[Response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaY4Y.png)

Does anyone of you have an idea how to fix this for chrome? Do you need additional information?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay found the solution. If anyone faces the same issue: I always used the incognito Chrome to avoid caching issues. And there was a setting that blocked all 3rd party cookies in incognito mode by default:

[Chrome 3rd party cookies incognito mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvMqh.png)

Once you change that to "accept", it works. Cheers